Pivot multiindex pandas dataframe
I am trying to reshape a multiindex pandas dataframe. A sample of the original dataframe is below.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['2023-06-30', '2023-07-31', '2023-08-31'],
    ['Post', 'Pre', 'Curr']
], names=['portdate', 'recontype'])
cols = ['begbal', 'unschd_pmt', 'unschd_part_pmt', 'unschd_full_pmt']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9,4), idx, cols)

My desired output would also be a multiindex dataframe. Something that looks like this.
                                6/30/2024 | 7/31/2023 | 8/31/2023
recontype  |  balancetype     |
Curr       |  begbal          | 0.130718  | 0.109284  | 0.642785
Curr       |  unschd_pmt      | 0.510886  | 0.940061  | 0.391445
Curr       |  unschd_part_pmt | 0.746261  | 0.431154  | 0.385217
Curr       |  unschd_full_pmt | 0.062011  | 0.170478  | 0.757842
Pre        |  begbal          | 0.566243  | 0.594380  | 0.694061
...
Post       |  begbal          | 0.729325  | 0.782333  | 0.465907
...

I can get the portdate attribute to columns using df.unstack(level=0) but I'm struggling to get the recontype attributes where I want them.
df.unstack(level=1).T keeps the portdate attribute as columns and the .T transposes the balancetype attribute to rows but they are at level 0 and there is a row for each recontype attribute. I'd like to flip that so that recontype is at level 0 and 'balancetypeis atlevel 1`.

Did you mean df.stack().unstack(0) ?
